# Async/await function not returning responses for all items when using .map

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a JSON object stored in a locations.json file.

```
[
  {
    "VendorName": "Vendor1",
    "VendorAddress": "Some Address",
    "VendorCity": "Some City",
    "VendorState": "NY",
    "Vendor_ZipCode": Some Zip Code,
  },
{
    "VendorName": "Vendor2",
    "VendorAddress": "Some Address2",
    "VendorCity": "Some City2",
    "VendorState": "NY",
    "Vendor_ZipCode": Some Zip Code2,
  },
 ]
```

I store this file in an object within myFile.js.

```
const locations = require("../../data/locations.json");
```

The main component which I need to calculate coordinates is:

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
```

I store the locations in a property within the Component class.

```
this.state = {locations}
```

Within the component class, I call a method within the componentDidMount Method called renderVendorMarkers.

```
async componentDidMount() {
...Some Code
this.renderVendorMarkers(this.state.locations);
}
```

In this method, I want to do the following (which isnt working):

1. Loop through each location within the locations object
2. store each individual location's address, city, and state in a
   string.
3. Use Location.geocodeAsync() to return the coordinates for each
   location.

The method itself that is being called looks like the following:

```
  renderVendorMarkers = async vendors => {
    vendors.map(async vendor => {
      const { VendorAddress, VendorCity, VendorState } = vendor;
      const fullAddress = `${VendorAddress}, ${VendorCity}, ${VendorState}`;
      const response = await Location.geocodeAsync(fullAddress);
      const [{ latitude, longitude }] = response;
      console.log(latitude, longitude);
    });
  };
```

I need this method to go through each location within my locations, run geocodeAsync and print out each vendor's geoLocation based on the concatenated string of Address, City, State.

I keep getting only the first coordinates with my console.log and it wont loop through the other location.

The expected outcome is to console.log an array of coordinates for all of the vendors in the locations object.  Let me know if I need to clarify further.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: i would suggest making your question short and clear. In the current format I get lost

Comment: What do you expect by doing map?

Comment: I wanted to use either map or the for each loop to go through each vendor, take the address, city and state, and use it to retrieve the coordinates using Location.geocodeAsync().  The goal for now is to just console.log out all of the coordinates (latitude, longitude) for each vendor.

Comment: If you want each vendor to only fetch its geocode sequentially instead of all at the same time, I'd recommend not using map or forEach, even if you make the inner function async it doesn't wait for the previous function to resolve before executing the next one. Might be related to your issue if you're being rate limited.

Comment: Thanks @Klaycon.  Do you have any suggestions on the best approach.  This is a proof of concept, but eventually the goal is to get user data from a database and use the addresses to get the coordinates and mark them on a map.  Im still a novice coder so besides .map or foreach, what would be a better method to use to parse through the json object, retrieve the address string and use an API or Location.geocodeAsync() to get the array of coordinates.

Comment: Map and forEach are great, but you can't instruct the external code to wait between calling the function for each element of the array. Since you want that level of control, just use a simple for loop so control flow never leaves your function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something is missing in your post. 
In my simple example calling an asynchronous function inside of map callback gets executed properly for each item of given array. 
Moreover if Promise.all is used, then it is even possible to map an array. 
It seems a little bit off, but actually something similar is done with RxJS libraries and its observables and map operator.

```js
const API = {};
API.data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const createPromise = (index, ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(API.data[index], ms))
});

const asyncFunc = async (index) => {
  return createPromise(index, 1000).then(data => data);
}
let locations = [1,2,3]


let squared = locations.map(async location => {
  let data = await asyncFunc(location - 1);
  console.log(location, data);
  return location*location;
});

console.log(squared)

const mapArrayAsynchronously = async (locations) => {
  return Promise.all(locations.map(async location => {
    let data = await asyncFunc(location - 1);
    return location*location;
    })).then(data => data);
}

f = async () => {
squared = await mapArrayAsynchronously(locations);
console.log(squared);
}

f();
```

Comment: I figured it out.  The Location.geocodeAsync method wasnt working properly.  I used fetch to get the coordinates from  the googlemaps api.  The issue was that the geocodeAsync wasnt meant for continuous use and the promises using async would be delayed on multiple uses.

Answer (score 0):

The goole maps api I used ended up working.  It returned an array of promises which had the coordinates inside.  Here is the code that worked.

```
//Method to determine the latitude and longitude for all vendors from Locations.JSON
  getCoordinates = vendors => {
    const APIKEY = "myApiKey"; //key hidden on purpose.  Use your api key
    const promises = vendors.map(async vendor => {
      const vendorID = vendor.VendorID;
      const fullAddress = `${vendor.VendorAddress},${vendor.VendorCity},${vendor.VendorState}`;
      try {
        const resp = await fetch(
          `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${fullAddress}&key=${APIKEY}`
        );
        const respJson = await resp.json();
        return respJson.results[0].geometry.location;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  };
```